# Child Theme - what is the scope of overwriting files?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, child-theme, wp-register-script

I noticed that creating twentythirteen-child/archive.php overwrites twentythirteen/archive.php but creating twentythirteen-child/shortcodes/drop-cap/drop-cap.php does not overwrite twentythirteen/shortcodes/drop-cap/drop-cap.php.

What does this depend on? Sub-folders aren't overwritten?

Similarly twentythirteen-child/shortcodes/drop-cap/drop-cap.css will not overwrite parent CSS file if called through `wp_enqueue_script();`. This means that `wp_dequeue_script()` and `wp_deregister_script()` must always exist for multiple CSS and JS files (and for PHP files in folders)?

Answer (score 0):

The files `include`d via the [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) function are replaceable. That can be a lot of files or only a few, depending on the theme. I think this answers most of your question.

The `functions.php` of a child theme is included in addition to the parent `functions.php`.

The `style.css` of the child replaces the parent. Other stylesheets should be `enqueue`d and can be removed via the mechanisms of that subsystem.

I have probably forgotten or missed something but that is the quick version.

Additional information is in the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: Yes, the first sentence answers everything :) I'll test this now and I think that `get_template_part` is the solution to everything that I was missing (i.e. replacing PHP files in sub-folders with ability to replace CSS and JS and not only PHP). I've read the article from Codex about Child Themes a few times but it doesn't mention how far a theme can go if it comes to modules (separate JS/CSS per module).